# Poor font quality in CCLabelBMFont

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, cocos2d-iphone

Scaled screenshot on iPhone 5S:

[image]

`CCLabelBMFont` is on top and `CCLabelTTF` is at the bottom.
Both strings use `Helvetica Neue Light 17pt`.

As you can see there is some kind of a stroke in the first string, but all symbols in font image are white on transparent background. Is it possible to get rid of this effect and make `CCLabelBMFont` look just as good as `CCLabelTTF`?

I used `bmGlyph` and other free analogs for Bitmap font creation, results were always the same.

Comment: Did you check the settings in bmGlyph for the stroke? There is a black stroke addded by default.

Comment: @TiborUdvari yes of course. I have already answered my question. I will accept it when I'll be able to do it.

Comment: Yeah I saw your answer. It just seems a bit odd. I never encountered this sort of errors with SP and bmGlyph. For me it works out of the box with the default settings. Happy you got it to work though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a relief!
Turned out it's because of `Blend src` property.
I changed this property on my label from default in SpriteBuilder 'One' to 'Dst Alpha' and now it's impossible to see any difference between `CCLabelTTF` and `CCLabelBMFont`!

Answer (score 0):

First, don't change the node's scale property or it will be blurry.

You need to make a HD version of the font, where the font's png filename has the -hd suffix and the font size is double that for non-Retina devices. For example:

Non-Retina font with 32pt size (if you support non-retina devices):

```
font.fnt
font.png
```

Then create a font with 64pt size and save it as:

```
font-hd.fnt
font-hd.png
```

Comment: Of course I use double size font for retina iPhone. 34pt in my case. Font is not scaled. I scaled image in editor to show the difference. I still get this black stroke on font. Now I'm thinking about buying the $40 font program, but I don't think it will change anything.