# Font is always fuzzy even HD image version

Tags: ios, fonts, cocos2d-x

I am using `Cocos2d-x` and loading in a .fnt file (created in `bmGlyph`) so that I can create a `CCLabelBMFont`. The thing that is frustrating is that the fonts are always fuzzy and blurry, even when it loads the HD variety.

```
distance_label = CCLabelBMFont::create("0", fntFile);
distance_label->setScale( 0.8 * CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getContentScaleFactor() );
distance_label->setPosition( ccp(distance_label->getContentSize().width/2.0 + 8, size.height - 60) );
this->addChild( distance_label );
```

Testing this on my iPhone 5.

Any ideas why the font would always be blurry and not crisp/high res looking?

Comment: this may have some relevance (not certain) ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349585/poor-font-quality-in-cclabelbmfont/23360207#23360207

Comment: Quality of fnt exported fonts depends upon tools. Check out other tools like GlyphDesigner, Littera, BMFont etc.

Answer (score 0):

.fnt files are raster fonts (not vector like True Type or Open Type fonts).  If the resolution at which the font was created is not at least as high as the target resolution, you will likely not be able to get a smooth image out of it.

Comment: I realize that. Using the `bmGlyph` app builds the files correctly, so that is why I don't get why they come out blurry.